# numpy.linalg.pinv() hangs for some infinite values (but not for others)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

In my code I need to compute pseudoinverse of matrices and it may happen that some of the elements of the matrix are infinite (`np.inf`). Sometimes the `pinv()` function handles it well and returns something, but sometimes it just hangs with 100% CPU usage and I need to kill the process. See the demonstration below:

```
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import numpy.linalg as la
In [3]: x = np.array([[550.0, 1], [1, np.inf]])
In [4]: la.pinv(x)
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
In [5]: x = np.array([[np.inf, np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf]])
In [6]: la.pinv(x)
Out[6]: 
array([[ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan]])
In [7]: x = np.array([[550.0, 1], [np.inf, np.inf]])
In [8]: la.pinv(x)  # here it just hung and I had to kill it from outside
Killed
```

Why does this happen? Why does it do fine for some arrangement of `inf`s but it just hangs for other? Might this be a bug (i.e. should the values be checked first)?

Comment: its odd that is doesn't hang for the opposite either
`x = np.array([[np.inf, np.inf], [550.0,1]])`
`la.pinv(x)`
array([[nan, nan],[nan, nan]])

Comment: also, none of the examples you provide (and the one I did) will pass the:
np.allclose(x, np.dot(x, np.dot(la.pinv(x), x))) test from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7461) on numpy's GitHub repository.

The answer is that it is a bug in BLAS/LAPACK/ATLAS and numpy (1.10.4) functions are just thin wrappers around procedures from those libraries which don't check the inputs beforehand as it harms performance.